# Matrix of a linear map that turns a vector space $V$ over $F$ into a $F[X]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

The following is from my lecture notes:

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, $\alpha : V\rightarrow V$ a linear map.

We consider $V$ as an $F[X]$-module via

$F[X]\times V \rightarrow V$

$(f(X),v) \mapsto f(\alpha)(v)$

Write $V_\alpha$ for this $F[X]$-module.

(I checked that this does indeed give a module.)

Next followed an example:

Suppose $V_\alpha \cong \frac{F[X]}{(X^n)}$ as $F[X]$-module.

Then (clearly) {$1+(X^n), X+(X^n),...X^{n-1}+(X^n)$} is a basis for $\frac{F[X]}{(X^n)}$ as an $F$-vector space.

With respect to this basis, $\alpha$ has matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
       0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 
       0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
       0 & \dots & 0  &1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \, ,
$$

since $\alpha$ acts as 'multiplication by $X$'.

**Question:** What is $\alpha$? If the action of $\alpha$ is to multiply by $X$, then it's clear that it has the matrix above with respect to the above basis. But why does $\alpha$ 'multiply by $X$ in the first place?

Comment: I'd appreciate any help with the matrix formatting.

Comment: I think I fixed the matrix. You basically had it: it's just \\ instead of //. Shouldn't the last column be all $0$s, though? $\alpha$ acts as $X$ by the definition of $V_\alpha$. As you say, an arbitrary polynomial $f \in F[X]$ acts as $f(\alpha)$, so for $f = X$, $f$ acts as $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

We know $\alpha : V \to V$ is some linear map, and we know that $X$ acts as $\alpha$. That is, $X \cdot \overline{v} = \alpha \overline{v}$. You've already done the hard work of showing that this extends to an action of all polynomials (that is, $V$ becomes an $F[X]$ module).

Up until this point, $\alpha$ was allowed to be *any* linear map. But now we hone in on a specific case. One thing that makes the $F[X]$-module theoretic lens so powerful is the way that (quite abstract) concepts in module theory descend to very concrete computational applications in matrix theory. For instance, as you may have noticed, the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over PIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain)<sup>1</sup> gives us the rational and jordan canonical forms almost for free!

In this problem, then, we're supposed to look at one special case of this idea. If we know that, module theoretically, $V \cong F[X] / (X^n)$, what does that tell us (concretely!) about our matrix $\alpha$?

Well, as you've noticed, $F[X]/(X^n)$ has a natural basis given by

$$\Big \{ 1, X, \ldots, X^{n-1} \Big \}$$

Here I'm writing $X$ for both itself *and* its coset in $F[X]/(X^n)$. This is *technically* an abuse of notation, but it's harmless and entirely standard.

More importantly, we must always ask ourselves: "what does this mean *concretely*?". In this case, we consult the isomorphism! We know
$\varphi : F[X] / (X^n) \cong V$, and so $\varphi(1)$ had better be *some* vector $\overline{v} \in V$.

But from this *one* vector, we actually know everything! Indeed:

$$\varphi(X) = \varphi(X \cdot 1) = X \cdot \varphi(1) = \alpha \overline{v}.$$

You should convince yourself that, in a similar way, our "obvious" basis in the abstract setting $\{1, X, \ldots, X^{n-1} \}$ descends to a (possibly much less obvious!) basis in the concrete setting:

$$\Big \{ \overline{v}, \alpha \overline{v}, \ldots, \alpha^{n-1} \overline{v} \Big \}.$$

In general, this basis may look totally bizarre when you see it written with concrete numbers. But from the abstract point of view, it is entirely natural. This, for what it's worth, is one of the main reasons to care about abstraction at all! From up in the clouds, we can see what really matters. Then by chasing through definitions we can find a concrete representation of our problem which is *abstractly* natural. This often has very important consequences for computation!
If you're sold on diagonalization, we're doing something which is morally very similar (even if the tools are higher powered).

My own preaching aside, though, it's time to reap the benefits of our new representation! We've found some new basis for $V$. It's now natural to ask "what does $\alpha$ look like with respect to this basis?". Of course, we know the answer. We *chose* this basis in order to make $\alpha$ look nice. Indeed, as you've noticed, $\alpha$ will correspond to a very simple nilpotent matrix.

So what have we learned? Take your favorite matrix $\alpha$. Define $X \cdot \overline{v}$ by $\alpha \overline{v}$. Extend this action to an action of $F[X]$ on $V$. Now ask yourself: "What is $V$ isomorphic to?". By module theory, it must look like a direct sum of subspaces $V_k$, each of which is isomorphic to $F[X] / I_k$ for some ideal $I_k$.

If there's only one piece, and the ideal $I$ happens to equal $(X^n)$ then we've characterized exactly what $\alpha$ can look like! As a (fun?) exercise, you might ask what happens when $I$ is some other ideal.

If this is ever feeling abstract (and it probably will at first!) you should take a step back, take a real honest-to-goodness matrix $\alpha$ (say in $3$ dimensions, and start with a matrix of full rank), and run this all by hand
(or perhaps with some software like [sage](https://sagemath.org)). Can you find an ideal $I \subseteq F[X]$ so that $V \cong F[X] / I$? Can you use this to find a basis which is "obviously nice" abstractly? What does this basis become concretely? Does this give you more control over $\alpha$? These are conceptually difficult problems to grapple with, but spending some time doing this will be extremely helpful for internalizing these ideas!

<sup>1:</sup> that *desperately* needs a shorter name...

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you SO much for the detailed answer!